# How to make content accesible from a RSS reader

Tags: php, html, rss

i want to make content accesible from a RSS reader .
i have the following code for the php page of the reader

```
<?php
try {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=k;charset=utf8', '', '', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

$myFile = "rss.xml";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$rss_txt ='';
$rss_txt .= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
$rss_txt .= "<rss version='2.0'>";
$rss_txt .= '<channel>';
$rss_txt .='<title>karolos.upatras.gr</title>';
$rss_txt .='<link>localohost/rss.php</link>';
$rss_txt .='<description>Latest Reports</description>';

echo "<pre>";
            var_dump($myFile);
            echo "</pre>";

$query = "SELECT * FROM spots ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 20";
$query->execute();
$results1 = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

foreach( $results1 as $row )
 {
        $id             =$row['id'];
        $rss_txt .= '<item>';

        $rss_txt .= '<title>' .$row['title']. '</title>';
        $rss_txt .= '<link>http:/repot_profile.php?id='.$id.'</link>';
        $rss_txt .= '<description>' .$row['description'] .$row['area']. '</description>';

        $rss_txt .= '</item>';

        echo "<pre>";
            var_dump($row['id']);
            echo "</pre>";
    echo "<pre>";
            var_dump($row['description']);
            echo "</pre>";
    }
$rss_txt .= '</channel>';
$rss_txt .= '</rss>';


fwrite($fh, $rss_txt);
fclose($fh);
header('Location: rss.xml');
?>
```

*report_profile.php is a webpage to show stats for the report
Can you help how can i link these to my index file so a RSS reader can access it and have these rows as an RSS feed

Im new to  RSS , PHP ,HTML ,etc.  so maybe this is a stupid question but its really hard for me to find a documentation about RSS mostly found RSS reader or embed RSS feeder

Comment: Do you want to make content available **to** an RSS reader? If so, you are attempting to create an RSS Feed. You will probably want to learn about [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php "PHP.net manual")

Comment: note `$query = "SELECT * FROM spots ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 20";` should be `$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM spots ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 20");`

Comment: thnx didnt notice that now works fine